# configuration custom errors gives "error too many redirects" in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I configured my config file for custom errors in MVC. So the custom error configurations are:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Views/UnAuthorized/ErrorUnauthorised"/>
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Views/UnAuthorized/ErrorResourceNotFound"/>
</customErrors>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"></deny>
  <allow users="*"></allow>
</authorization>
```

and for the server

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
  <remove statusCode="401" />
  <error statusCode="401" path="http://localhost:port/UnAuthorized/ErrorUnauthorised" responseMode="Redirect" />
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="http://localhost:port/UnAuthorized/ErrorResourceNotFound" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
```

My Error pages are in different folder with other config file which allows unauthenticated users with:

```
  <allow users="*"></allow>
```

My Error pages controller is:

```
  public class UnAuthorizedController : Controller
{
    // GET: UnAuthorized

    public ActionResult ErrorUnauthorised()
    {
        return View("ErrorUnauthorised");
    }

    public ActionResult ErrorResourceNotFound()
    {
        return View("ErrorResourceNotFound");
    }
}
```

When I try to start application it starts with this page ~/Views/UnAuthorized/ErrorUnauthorised and shows browser message "Too many redirects" When I remove httpErrors  section the application starts normally with Index page, but on error it doesn't shows the custom error pages

**EDIT**
I ended up with conclusion that application shows error "too many redirects" if I have both 401 and 404 errors in my config file. If I remove the 401 error the application is working fine

Comment: Please check if you have created ErrorUnauthorised, ErrorResourceNotFound views. Too many redirect is coming because of server is giving either 401,404 status code on each request.

Comment: Yes I have views for each page and "too many redirects" messages stops to appear when I remove httpErrors  section, so I guess it's not from the views

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the httpErrors tag. Just add the following under system.web

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="errorpage.htm?error=1" >
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="filenotfound.htm?error=1" />
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="notauthorized.htm?error=1" />
</customErrors>
```

notes:

1- I add the '?error=1' query string to inform asp.net that i dont want the aspxerrorpath query string to be added when an error occurs.

2- Put your .htm files at the application root folder.

3- If you have some messages you need to generate with c# code and display them inside the error pages then use the application_error event in global.asax to catch the relevant error and redirect the user to desired page.

Comment: It doesn't handle 401 error. It shows me Authentication window asking for password and username for that specific page, when I cancel the Authentication window it throws 401 error, not my custom NotAuthorized page

Comment: mmm, sorry i never tried to handle the windows auth window this way. Try to find a way to handle it through code, it must be an event in global.asax file.